What's the model of this Create Bikes Co. Bike
I find this bike by Create Bikes Co. really cool and interesting and would like to know the exact model of this bike. It uses a coaster brake for the rear. And I really love the dual seat stay tubes.

I got the image from this site http://www.curriqui.es/foro_tema_np.php?xtema=1100165
Let me know if anyone have any ideas.
And if anyone owns a bike like this let me see your builds. I really think it's cool for a bike touring build.
Thank you so much to anyone who could help.

I think there's lots of bikes like this out there, it shouldn't be too hard to find an equivalent one (from a different brand). It seems like Create Bikes is out of business.

PS: Just Google "Coaster Brake Singlespeed" or similar. Although using a coaster brake for a touring bike might not be a good idea, as they aren't strong enough for high loads (luggage). In hilly terrain (bound to happen on long tours) the brake might overheat and the lack of gears makes climbing (with luggage) difficult.

You have valid points, @Erlkoenig, but none of them outweigh "really cool"!

FWIW It seems this particular model is simply called 'Coaster' or 'Coaster Semi Fixie'.

I just really like the frame and fork. I'll probably use a different wheelset without coaster brakes.

A bicycle is one of the most efficient mean of transport, part of the pleasure we find in pedalling is the (hidden) fact that the bicycle is a multiplier of our efforts, i.e. with the same effort we ride 4 times the distance we would walk.
However, this efficiency comes from design, get the frame wrong and riding the bike will feel like a punishment. This is the difference you feel between riding a BSO (Bicycle Shaped Object) and a properly designed bicycle. Although the BSO is still giving you some 2x/3x advantage over walking, if your body ever rode a proper bicycle, it will feel the difference and it will find riding a BSO an unpleasant thing to do (mostly because of mental expectations).
A dual seat stay tubes system like the one in the picture serves no purpose, a part from making the bike very heavy on the back and therefore giving a cumbersome handling, even to an originally properly designed bicycle.
Since you like the style, you have two options:

buy a similar bicycle with steel frame and ask a framebuilder to solder the duplicated seat stay tubes: expensive, but you will pay someone real work. I suggest you to go this way if you never rode a proper bicycle, you would not be disappointed;
have a look for mixte bycicles, they are not exactly the same, but you may get interesting ideas and you may find excellent bicycles (as the Bridgestone Mixte 400 ) or very average bikes as the Schwinn Mirada;

